# JobService skips some sms in android oreo

Tags: java, android, sms, android-8.0-oreo, jobservice

I am creating a job service. 
This  service will be triggered based on change in sms(sent), works fine but failed to catch some messages.

```
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, jobTest.class);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");

    JobInfo.TriggerContentUri triggerContentUri = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        triggerContentUri = new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(uri,
                JobInfo.TriggerContentUri.FLAG_NOTIFY_FOR_DESCENDANTS);
    }

    JobInfo.Builder builder = new
            JobInfo.Builder(1, component).addTriggerContentUri(triggerContentUri);

    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)
            context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
```

I am catching only sent messages through this job,When i sent multiple messages to a number, it catches only latest message.

I don't want to use foreground service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to trigger immediately,You need to add setTriggerContentMaxDelay

```
 JobInfo.Builder builder = new
            JobInfo.Builder(1, component).addTriggerContentUri(triggerContentUri).setTriggerContentMaxDelay(0);
```